# Python and PowerPoint replace '<br><br>' becomes '_x000D_'

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm creating a PowerPoint with Python pptx and my query result string contains the html '`<br><br>`' and I'm trying to replace it with '\n' like:

```
TDsFirst = "\n" + self.TxtStringFromSQLserver.replace('<br><br>', '\n')
TDPs = TDPsFirst.replace('<br>', '\n')
TipDPsText_run.text = TDPs
```

This results in the lines ending with '`_x000D_`'

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert the '`<br>`' to returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is a little bit new, but is the expected behavior:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#pptx.text.text._Run.text

A run can only contain text. A line-break or paragraph boundary happens at a higher level. In particular, a line-break can only occur between runs, inside a paragraph. A paragraph "break" can only occur in a text-frame, between, well, paragraphs.

So depending on what you're trying to do, the solution may just be to make the assignment at the text-frame level rather than the run level as your variable-name `TipDPsText_run` suggests. Line-feed characters (`\n`) are accepted by `TextFrame.text` and are turned into paragraph boundaries.

That may not entirely solve the problem, but it may (I give it an 90% likelihood) and will at least change the question to one that can be solved.

**UPDATE:** After further review of the code, in fact a newline by itself `"\x0A"` is accepted by `Run.text` and placed unchanged into the XML where it probably looks pretty much like a line-break. This legacy courtesy does not extend to carriage-return `"\x0D"` which is rendered just as you see as `"_x000D_"`. This extra CR byte is in there because you're running on Windows. Accordingly, you may be able to work around this by using `"\x0A"` instead of `"\n"` in your text assignment. But I recommend the text-frame level assignment as the more approach more consistent with PowerPoint behavior, where typing in a carriage-return creates a new paragraph.

Comment: Ok, it seems the '\r' and the '\n' were both problematic because this does the trick:
 TDPs = TDPs.replace('\n', '\x0A')
 TDPs = TDPs.replace('\r', '\x0A')

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint handles only `0x0a` as a line break. When you use the "Python pptx" to create an extra line in a single placeholder, if the source text contains a `0x0d` code, the output page shows a strange word `_x000D_` at the end of the line. So I made a simple filter to fix that problem.

This simple code replaces `\r\n` with a single `\n`.

```
def office_comp(usr_txt):
    u_items = usr_txt.splitlines()
    return '\n'.join(u_items)
```

Then use the Python pptx such as:

```
new_slide.placeholders[p].text = office_comp(your_text_asis)
```